# Sum pivoted columns

Tags: asp.net, sql, pivot

I have this gridview with pivoted data:

```
    Store        MEX       USA
    Supermarket  10,000    5,000
    Club         10,000        0
    Direct        4,000    1,000
```

Is done with this query:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Sales] 
    PIVOT ( 
            SUM(Sales) 
            FOR Region IN ( [MEX], [USA] ) 
    ) AS SalesPerRegion
```

Now i want to add on the footer the TOTAL of the sales in MEX and USA, and i don't have idea how to do it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: if you could figure out how to toss it into your gridview you could also append `COMPUTE SUM([MEX]), SUM([USA]` on the end of your query (with the `SELECT` syntax @bluefeet provided as "`SELECT Store, MEX, USA`")

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `UNION ALL` to get a Total `SUM()` for each region

```
SELECT Store, MEX, USA 
FROM [Sales] 
PIVOT ( 
        SUM(Sales) 
        FOR Region IN ( [MEX], [USA] ) 
) AS SalesPerRegion

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total', Sum(MEX), Sum(USA)
FROM
(
    SELECT Store, MEX, USA 
    FROM [Sales] 
    PIVOT ( 
           SUM(Sales) 
           FOR Region IN ( [MEX], [USA] ) 
    ) AS SalesPerRegion
) x
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bea32/1)